# how to create a cascade of Slanted / Skewed divs with background-image

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image, skew

I'm willing to create something specific like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdk9B.png

with the background colors representing background-images.

My approach was to create a general div with children divs acting as parents for the divs where the images are going and rotate them (each parent div child of the general one).With a random rotation between -11deg and 11deg and its respective negative rotation on the images div to counter its parent rotation. The main problem I am encountering is that I use absolute position for this purpose and I lose the hability to wrap my images inside its parent divs.

I am using jquery to rotate each odd and even div on a positive or negative degree and the same to counter its rotation on the images.

I need to know if there is a way to do achieve this design, and if there was, see the light at the end of the tunel because I have been stuck with this for days...

Thanks everyone :D

My general structure right now is this:

```js
$('.rotated-divs').children().each(function () {

 if($(this).parent().children().index(this)%2 == 0){ 
    $(this).css({"transform":"rotate(11deg)"});

    if($(this).parent().children().index(this) > 1){
  $(this).css({"top":"-150px"});//.css({"transform":"rotate(11deg)"})

 }
 }

 else{
   $(this).css({"transform":"rotate(-11deg)","top":"-150px"});
 }
 
});

 $(".img-container:even").css({"transform":"rotate(-11deg)"});
 $(".img-container:odd").css({"transform":"rotate(11deg)"});
```

```css
.rotated-divs{

 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: -100px;
 overflow: hidden;
  
 .div-r{
  width: 250%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid yellow;

  .img-container{
   width: 75vw;
   height: 100%;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   position: absolute;
   left: 100px;
   
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated-divs">
  <div class="div-r" >
   <div  class="img-container" style="background-image: url(img/01.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-r">
   <div  class="img-container" style="background-image: url(img/02.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-r">
   <div  class="img-container" style="background-image: url(img/03.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-r">
   <div  class="img-container" style="background-image: url(img/04.jpg);"></div>
  </div>

  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graphic you posted, I can see that although you want slanted edges, the actual text inside the boxes shouldn't be slanted.

Given this criteria, I think you need to stop thinking about CSS transforms as the way to achieve it. Even if you can get it working, all that positive and negative rotation is a big waste of CPU effort for the browser.

Some better options:

1. Use SVG graphics. Drawing arbitrary shapes isn't really what HTML/CSS is good at. Your browser comes with an awesome ability to draw spot graphics, in the form of SVG. You should make use of it -- this kind of effect is trivial to draw in SVG. The only caveat is browser support; if you need to support IE8 and earlier, then be aware that they don't have SVG. But other than that, it's probably the best option.
2. Use CSS triangles (ie the border hack) to create the angled edges of your div boxes. With all the interlocking boxes, this might be quite tricky to pull off perfectly with CSS triangles, but it can be done, and browser support goes right back to IE6.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I kind of knew that doing it with css would be tricky and did not really know if it could be done. My question here is, even if I used SVG could I set my images as background-images of those svg? The compatibility is not a problem, IE 9+ is good for me :D

Comment: Yes, several ways: (1) SVG can have embedded images, so you can have a background image in your SVG; or (2) SVG can be styled with CSS, so you can set a `background-image`; or (3) SGV (or parts of it) can be transparent, so you could layer it on top of another element with the background image.